# Do we need to downvote posts of New Contributors?

Tags: discussion

I can see nowadays, more than two downvotes on posts of newbies to the site (SE) or instant closure of question. I don't feel one will wantedly ask Low quality posts, either they might lack knowledge about that particular topic or Stack Exchange, confusing with other sites like quora. So, Like @uhoh commented in one of a question, I feel it is a  unwelcoming trait, instead we can as ask them to improve their post and then reopen it if the question was closed. What is your opinion ?

Comment: `+1` different but related: [Too many downvote on questions recently?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/784/7982)

Comment: This is asked on the main Meta from time to time.  e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3515/236563 , https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258582/236563 to name but two

Comment: @Chenmunka each of the [nearly 200 *different* SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) each associated community is different, answers in the main meta site are way too generalized to apply to a low question rate, specialized yet universally interesting and unique site like Astronomy SE. We can be a lot nicer and more helpful *and welcoming* to new users by holding back on the down and close votes in cases where they only need a little help and guidance to build their question asking skills.

Comment: I agree.  However, each site can take into account how the other sites do things.  To try to establish a best practice.

Comment: @Chenmunka but each site can also try to do better, no? I don't think that folks that hang out in and opine on the main meta are the best ones to provide guidance how Astronomy SE can best be welcoming to budding astronomers and folks simply curious about what's up there. I think that if we try, we can *do better* than what a quick meta answer post can imagine.

Comment: @Chenmunka and don't forget to add the `@` when responding to a comment. Here's a meta post that's suitable for all sites: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/303080)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, No one will wantedly ask low quality posts (except questions that lacks effort). At the same time, its not whether the whole of SE is like this or that or not, why cant Astronomy SE be a good model ? New contributors do need some encouragement to keep them intact with site as well as knowledge. Not everyone can know everything, some still may not have enough knowledge about SE incl *me*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do we need to downvote posts of New Contributors?

No, we *really don't!*

This is a low question rate site, so we don't need to be in triage mode.

The problem with quick down votes on new users' first questions is that they get discouraged and give up, whereas if we are encouraging and helpful and work to improve the question, they may continue to be engaged on the site.

I shouldn't have to remind folks, but getting new users to be engaged on the site and helping them ask good questions is a good thing!

Also, those down voters will frequently forget to go check back to see if there's been an improvement that would trigger them to change their vote. You can always down vote at a later date. With only a half-dozen questions per day, it is not hard to see yesterday's questions here.

Comment: +1. Absolutely. And yes, If any edit has been made, it is clearly visible in Top Questions.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on whether the question can be improved or not.

A question that is just vague or hard to understand, I might leave a comment - I wouldn't usually downvote.

A question that shows no effort, tries to solicit answers for the apparent purpose of assistance with homework or assessment, propagates personal or "fringe" theories or has ulterior motives - I downvote.

Comment: " "fringe" theories or has ulterior motives - I downvote." definitely